# Apple script to toggle comment/uncomment in Script Editor?

Tags: applescript

I want Apple script which allows me to toggle comment/uncomment in Script Editor, using `(*` and `*)`.

I found this [link](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=34501), but it is not exactly what I am looking for. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the script, which is in your Mac:

`/Library/Scripts/Script Editor Scripts/Comment Tags.scpt`